# Java: Save Image Of DrawingBoard(JComponent) Using A File Chooser.

Tags: java, jfilechooser, jcomponent

The program allows for painting and then when you click on the File>Export , the content of the DrawingBoard is then exported to a JPeg format which is saved to the desktop. 
But when saved, the image appears & the background is black (problem) even if stated that it must be White.

I also want the program to ask the user where to save the image and then the image is saved.

Can you please solve this? and help me add the FileChooser
. I dont know where to put it.

This is my code: Please Help.

```html
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Lesson49_1 extends JFrame 
{
 JMenuBar menubar;
        JMenu File, Exit;
        JMenuItem New,Open;
        JComponent DrawingBoard;
        
  JButton brushBut, lineBut, ellipseBut, rectBut, strokeBut, fillBut;
  
  // Slider used to change the transparency
  
  JSlider transSlider;
  
  JLabel transLabel;
  
  // Makes sure the float for transparency only shows 2 digits
  
  DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
  
  // Contains all of the rules for drawing 
  
  Graphics2D graphSettings;
  
  // Homework use graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5F));
  // To change the stroke dynamically with a component
  
  // Going to be used to monitor what shape to draw next
  
  int currentAction = 1;
  
  // Transparency of the shape
  
  float transparentVal = 1.0f;
  
  // Default stroke and fill colors
  
  Color strokeColor=Color.RED, fillColor=Color.WHITE;
 
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
                new Lesson49_1();
        }

        public Lesson49_1()
        {
         // Define the defaults for the JFrame
         
            this.setSize(800, 600);
            this.setTitle("Java Paint");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
                      
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        
        // Add the menubar to the frame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        // Define and add two drop down menu to the menubar
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu  dbMenu = new JMenu("Database");
        JMenu  ToolsMenu = new JMenu("Tools");
        JMenu  HelpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
          menuBar.add(dbMenu);
          menuBar.add(ToolsMenu);
          menuBar.add(HelpMenu);  
        // Create and add simple menu item to one of the drop down menu
        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New Project");
        JMenuItem openAction = new JMenuItem("Open File");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteAction = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        JMenuItem UndoAction = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        JMenuItem RedoAction = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        JMenuItem clearAction = new JMenuItem("Clear");
        JMenuItem saveAction = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exportAction = new JMenuItem("Export");
        JMenuItem printAction = new JMenuItem("Print");
        JMenuItem ConvertAction = new JMenuItem("Convert To Tables");
        JMenuItem ColorAction = new JMenuItem("Color Picker");
        JMenuItem ZoomAction = new JMenuItem("Zoom");
        JMenuItem EntityAction = new JMenuItem("Entity & Attributes");
        JMenuItem RelationshipAction = new JMenuItem("Relationship Attributes");
        JMenuItem HelpAction = new JMenuItem("Help");
        JMenuItem AboutAction = new JMenuItem("About");
        
        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(openAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(saveAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exportAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(printAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitAction);
        
        
        editMenu.add(UndoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(RedoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(cutAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(copyAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(pasteAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(clearAction);
        
        dbMenu.add(ConvertAction);
        
        ToolsMenu.add(ColorAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(ZoomAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(EntityAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(RelationshipAction);
        
        HelpMenu.add(HelpAction);
        HelpMenu.addSeparator();        
        HelpMenu.add(AboutAction);
        
                
            
            
            
         newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                      
               new Lesson49_1().setVisible(true);          
            }
        });   
            
            
         
         
            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            
            // Swing box that will hold all the buttons
            
            Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
            
            // Make all the buttons in makeMeButtons by passing the
            // button icon. 
            
            brushBut = makeMeButtons("./src/brush.png", 1);
            lineBut = makeMeButtons("./src/line.png", 2);
            ellipseBut = makeMeButtons("./src/ellipse.png", 3);
            rectBut = makeMeButtons("./src/rectangle.png", 4);
            
            // Make all the buttons in makeMeColorButton by passing the
            // button icon and true for stroke color or false for fill
            
            strokeBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/stroke.png", 5, true);
            fillBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/fill.png", 6, false);
            
            // Add the buttons to the box
            
            theBox.add(brushBut);
            theBox.add(lineBut);
            theBox.add(ellipseBut);
            theBox.add(rectBut);
            theBox.add(strokeBut);
            theBox.add(fillBut);
            
            // Add the transparent label and slider
            
            transLabel = new JLabel("Transparent: 1");
            
            // Min value, Max value and starting value for slider
            
            transSlider = new JSlider(1, 99, 99);
            
            // Create an instance of ListenForEvents to handle events
            
            ListenForSlider lForSlider = new ListenForSlider();
            
            // Tell Java that you want to be alerted when an event
            // occurs on the slider
           
            transSlider.addChangeListener(lForSlider);

            theBox.add(transLabel);
            theBox.add(transSlider);

            buttonPanel.add(theBox);
           
            this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
            
            // Make the drawing area take up the rest of the frame
            
           // this.add(new DrawingBoard(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            DrawingBoard drawPanel = new DrawingBoard();
            this.add(drawPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER );
            this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            
             exportAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
              BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(drawPanel.getWidth(), drawPanel.getHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
drawPanel.paint(g);
                 try{
                     ImageIO.write(image,"png", new File("C:\\Users\\Wenda\\Desktop\\Image.png"));
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Image Saved to desktop");
                     }
                 catch(Exception ex){
                      ex.printStackTrace();
                     }


                
            }
        });   
         
            // Show the frame
            
            this.setVisible(true);
            
            
        }
        
        // Spits out buttons based on the image supplied
        // actionNum represents each shape to be drawn
        
        public JButton makeMeButtons(String iconFile, final int actionNum){
         JButton theBut = new JButton();
            Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
            theBut.setIcon(butIcon);
            
            // Make the proper actionPerformed method execute when the
            // specific button is pressed
            
            theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     currentAction = actionNum;
     
    }
            });
            
            return theBut;  
        }
        
        // Spits out buttons based on the image supplied and
        // whether a stroke or fill is to be defined
        
        public JButton makeMeColorButton(String iconFile, final int actionNum, final boolean stroke){
         JButton theBut = new JButton();
            Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
            theBut.setIcon(butIcon);
            
            theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     
     if(stroke){
      
      // JColorChooser is a popup that lets you pick a color
      
      strokeColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,  "Pick a Stroke", Color.BLACK);
     } else {
      fillColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,  "Pick a Fill", Color.WHITE);
     }
     
    }
            });
            
            return theBut;  
        }

        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        public  class DrawingBoard extends JComponent
        {
         
         // ArrayLists that contain each shape drawn along with
         // that shapes stroke and fill
         
                ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
                ArrayList<Color> shapeFill = new ArrayList<Color>();
                ArrayList<Color> shapeStroke = new ArrayList<Color>();
                ArrayList<Float> transPercent = new ArrayList<Float>();
                
                Point drawStart, drawEnd;

                // Monitors events on the drawing area of the frame
                
                public DrawingBoard()
                {
                 
                        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
                          {
                         
                            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
                            {
                             
                             if(currentAction != 1){
                             
                             // When the mouse is pressed get x & y position
                             
                             drawStart = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                             drawEnd = drawStart;
                                repaint();
                                
                             }
                             
                                
                                }

                            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
                                {
                             
                             if(currentAction != 1){
                             
                               // Create a shape using the starting x & y
                               // and finishing x & y positions
                             
                             Shape aShape = null;
                             
                             if (currentAction == 2){
                              aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                e.getX(), e.getY());
                             } else 
                             
                             if (currentAction == 3){
                              aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                e.getX(), e.getY());
                             } else 
                             
                             if (currentAction == 4) {
                              
                              // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates
                              
                                    aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                      e.getX(), e.getY());
                             }
                             
                                  
                                  // Add shapes, fills and colors to there ArrayLists
                                  
                                  shapes.add(aShape);
                                  shapeFill.add(fillColor);
                                  shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                                  
                                  // Add transparency value to ArrayList
                                  
                                  transPercent.add(transparentVal);
                                  
                                  drawStart = null;
                                  drawEnd = null;
                                  
                                  // repaint the drawing area
                                  
                                  repaint();
                                  
                             }
                                  
                                }
                          } );

                        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
                        {
                         
                          public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
                          {
                           
                           // If this is a brush have shapes go on the screen quickly
                           
                           if(currentAction == 1){
                         
                         int x = e.getX();
                         int y = e.getY();
                         
                         Shape aShape = null;
                         
                         // Make stroke and fill equal to eliminate the fact that this is an ellipse
                         
                         strokeColor = fillColor;
                         
                         aShape = drawBrush(x,y,5,5);
                         
                         shapes.add(aShape);
                                  shapeFill.add(fillColor);
                                  shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                                  
                                  // Add the transparency value
                                  
                                  transPercent.add(transparentVal);
                        } 
                           
                         // Get the final x & y position after the mouse is dragged
                           
                         drawEnd = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                            repaint();
                          }
                        } );
                }
                

                public void paint(Graphics g)
                {
                  // Class used to define the shapes to be drawn
                 
                        graphSettings = (Graphics2D)g;

                        // Antialiasing cleans up the jagged lines and defines rendering rules
                        
                        graphSettings.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                        
                        // Defines the line width of the stroke
                        
                        graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

                        // Iterators created to cycle through strokes and fills
                        Iterator<Color> strokeCounter = shapeStroke.iterator();
                        Iterator<Color> fillCounter = shapeFill.iterator();
                        
                        // Iterator for transparency
                        
                        Iterator<Float> transCounter = transPercent.iterator();
                        
                        for (Shape s : shapes)
                        {
                         
                         // Sets the shapes transparency value
                            
                            graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                                    AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transCounter.next()));
                         
                         // Grabs the next stroke from the color arraylist
                         graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());
                         
                         graphSettings.draw(s);
                         
                         // Grabs the next fill from the color arraylist
                         graphSettings.setPaint(fillCounter.next());
                         
                         graphSettings.fill(s);
                        }

                        // Guide shape used for drawing
                        if (drawStart != null && drawEnd != null)
                        {
                         // Makes the guide shape transparent
                            
                            graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                                    AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));
                         
                            // Make guide shape gray for professional look
                            
                         graphSettings.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                         
                         Shape aShape = null;
                         
                         if (currentAction == 2){
                          aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                  drawEnd.x, drawEnd.y);
                         } else 
                         
                         if (currentAction == 3){
                          aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                  drawEnd.x, drawEnd.y);
                         } else 
                         
                         if (currentAction == 4) {
                          
                          // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates
                          
                                aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                  drawEnd.x, drawEnd.y);
                         }
                                
                                
                                graphSettings.draw(aShape);
                        }
                }

                private Rectangle2D.Float drawRectangle(
                        int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
                {
                 // Get the top left hand corner for the shape
                 // Math.min returns the points closest to 0
                 
                        int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
                        int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
                        
                        // Gets the difference between the coordinates and 
                        
                        int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
                        int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

                        return new Rectangle2D.Float(
                                x, y, width, height);
                }
                
                // The other shapes will work similarly
                // More on this in the next tutorial
                
                private Ellipse2D.Float drawEllipse(
                        int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
                {
                        int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
                        int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
                        int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
                        int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

                        return new Ellipse2D.Float(
                                x, y, width, height);
                }
                
                private Line2D.Float drawLine(
                        int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
                {

                        return new Line2D.Float(
                                x1, y1, x2, y2);
                }
                
                private Ellipse2D.Float drawBrush(
                        int x1, int y1, int brushStrokeWidth, int brushStrokeHeight)
                {
                 
                 return new Ellipse2D.Float(
                            x1, y1, brushStrokeWidth, brushStrokeHeight);
                 
                }

        }
        
     // Implements ActionListener so it can react to events on components
        
        private class ListenForSlider implements ChangeListener{
         
         // Called when the spinner is changed
         
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         
          // Check if the source of the event was the button
         
          if(e.getSource() == transSlider){
         
           // Change the value for the label next to the spinner
           // Use decimal format to make sure only 2 decimals are ever displayed
         
           transLabel.setText("Transparent: " + dec.format(transSlider.getValue() * .01) );
           
           // Set the value for transparency for every shape drawn after
           
           transparentVal = (float) (transSlider.getValue() * .01);
           
          }
         
         }
         
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use drawPanel.paint, use drawPanel.print or drawPanel.printAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had 1 compile error that I had to fix.  You have several input png images that I didn't have.

I added the JFileChooser to your export action listener.  I also formatted your Java application.

You should paint on a JPanel and override the paintComponent method.  I fixed the black background by creating an ARGB BufferedImage.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.fse;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Lesson49_1 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -140274271716086522L;

    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu File, Exit;
    JMenuItem New, Open;
    JComponent DrawingBoard;

    JButton brushBut, lineBut, ellipseBut, rectBut, strokeBut, fillBut;

    // Slider used to change the transparency

    JSlider transSlider;

    JLabel transLabel;

    // Makes sure the float for transparency only shows 2 digits

    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    // Contains all of the rules for drawing

    Graphics2D graphSettings;

    // Homework use graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5F));
    // To change the stroke dynamically with a component

    // Going to be used to monitor what shape to draw next

    int currentAction = 1;

    // Transparency of the shape

    float transparentVal = 1.0f;

    // Default stroke and fill colors

    Color strokeColor = Color.RED, fillColor = Color.WHITE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Lesson49_1();
    }

    public Lesson49_1() {
        // Define the defaults for the JFrame

        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setTitle("Java Paint");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // Add the menubar to the frame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // Define and add two drop down menu to the menubar
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu dbMenu = new JMenu("Database");
        JMenu ToolsMenu = new JMenu("Tools");
        JMenu HelpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(dbMenu);
        menuBar.add(ToolsMenu);
        menuBar.add(HelpMenu);
        // Create and add simple menu item to one of the drop down menu
        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New Project");
        JMenuItem openAction = new JMenuItem("Open File");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteAction = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        JMenuItem UndoAction = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        JMenuItem RedoAction = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        JMenuItem clearAction = new JMenuItem("Clear");
        JMenuItem saveAction = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exportAction = new JMenuItem("Export");
        JMenuItem printAction = new JMenuItem("Print");
        JMenuItem ConvertAction = new JMenuItem("Convert To Tables");
        JMenuItem ColorAction = new JMenuItem("Color Picker");
        JMenuItem ZoomAction = new JMenuItem("Zoom");
        JMenuItem EntityAction = new JMenuItem("Entity & Attributes");
        JMenuItem RelationshipAction = new JMenuItem("Relationship Attributes");
        JMenuItem HelpAction = new JMenuItem("Help");
        JMenuItem AboutAction = new JMenuItem("About");

        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(openAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(saveAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exportAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(printAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitAction);

        editMenu.add(UndoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(RedoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(cutAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(copyAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(pasteAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(clearAction);

        dbMenu.add(ConvertAction);

        ToolsMenu.add(ColorAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(ZoomAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(EntityAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(RelationshipAction);

        HelpMenu.add(HelpAction);
        HelpMenu.addSeparator();
        HelpMenu.add(AboutAction);

        newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                new Lesson49_1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        // Swing box that will hold all the buttons

        Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

        // Make all the buttons in makeMeButtons by passing the
        // button icon.

        brushBut = makeMeButtons("./src/brush.png", 1);
        lineBut = makeMeButtons("./src/line.png", 2);
        ellipseBut = makeMeButtons("./src/ellipse.png", 3);
        rectBut = makeMeButtons("./src/rectangle.png", 4);

        // Make all the buttons in makeMeColorButton by passing the
        // button icon and true for stroke color or false for fill

        strokeBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/stroke.png", 5, true);
        fillBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/fill.png", 6, false);

        // Add the buttons to the box

        theBox.add(brushBut);
        theBox.add(lineBut);
        theBox.add(ellipseBut);
        theBox.add(rectBut);
        theBox.add(strokeBut);
        theBox.add(fillBut);

        // Add the transparent label and slider

        transLabel = new JLabel("Transparent: 1");

        // Min value, Max value and starting value for slider

        transSlider = new JSlider(1, 99, 99);

        // Create an instance of ListenForEvents to handle events

        ListenForSlider lForSlider = new ListenForSlider();

        // Tell Java that you want to be alerted when an event
        // occurs on the slider

        transSlider.addChangeListener(lForSlider);

        theBox.add(transLabel);
        theBox.add(transSlider);

        buttonPanel.add(theBox);

        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        // Make the drawing area take up the rest of the frame

        // this.add(new DrawingBoard(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        final DrawingBoard drawPanel = new DrawingBoard();
        this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        exportAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(drawPanel.getWidth(),
                        drawPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                drawPanel.paint(g);
                g.dispose();

                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                File theDirectory = new File("C:/Users/Wenda/Desktop");
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(theDirectory);
                FileNameExtensionFilter pngFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "PNG file (*.png)", "png");
                fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pngFilter);
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(pngFilter);

                int status = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(Lesson49_1.this);

                if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(image, "png",
                                fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image saved to "
                                + fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        // Show the frame

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    // Spits out buttons based on the image supplied
    // actionNum represents each shape to be drawn

    public JButton makeMeButtons(String iconFile, final int actionNum) {
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);

        // Make the proper actionPerformed method execute when the
        // specific button is pressed

        theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentAction = actionNum;

            }
        });

        return theBut;
    }

    // Spits out buttons based on the image supplied and
    // whether a stroke or fill is to be defined

    public JButton makeMeColorButton(String iconFile, final int actionNum,
            final boolean stroke) {
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);

        theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (stroke) {

                    // JColorChooser is a popup that lets you pick a color

                    strokeColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,
                            "Pick a Stroke", Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    fillColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick a Fill",
                            Color.WHITE);
                }

            }
        });

        return theBut;
    }

    public class DrawingBoard extends JComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4431176095451940075L;

        // ArrayLists that contain each shape drawn along with
        // that shapes stroke and fill
        ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        ArrayList<Color> shapeFill = new ArrayList<Color>();
        ArrayList<Color> shapeStroke = new ArrayList<Color>();
        ArrayList<Float> transPercent = new ArrayList<Float>();

        Point drawStart, drawEnd;

        // Monitors events on the drawing area of the frame

        public DrawingBoard() {

            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    if (currentAction != 1) {

                        // When the mouse is pressed get x & y position

                        drawStart = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        drawEnd = drawStart;
                        repaint();

                    }

                }

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                    if (currentAction != 1) {

                        // Create a shape using the starting x & y
                        // and finishing x & y positions

                        Shape aShape = null;

                        if (currentAction == 2) {
                            aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                    e.getX(), e.getY());
                        } else

                        if (currentAction == 3) {
                            aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                    e.getX(), e.getY());
                        } else

                        if (currentAction == 4) {

                            // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates

                            aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                                    e.getX(), e.getY());
                        }

                        // Add shapes, fills and colors to there ArrayLists

                        shapes.add(aShape);
                        shapeFill.add(fillColor);
                        shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);

                        // Add transparency value to ArrayList

                        transPercent.add(transparentVal);

                        drawStart = null;
                        drawEnd = null;

                        // repaint the drawing area

                        repaint();

                    }

                }
            });

            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                    // If this is a brush have shapes go on the screen quickly

                    if (currentAction == 1) {

                        int x = e.getX();
                        int y = e.getY();

                        Shape aShape = null;

                        // Make stroke and fill equal to eliminate the fact that
                        // this is an ellipse

                        strokeColor = fillColor;

                        aShape = drawBrush(x, y, 5, 5);

                        shapes.add(aShape);
                        shapeFill.add(fillColor);
                        shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);

                        // Add the transparency value

                        transPercent.add(transparentVal);
                    }

                    // Get the final x & y position after the mouse is dragged

                    drawEnd = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // Class used to define the shapes to be drawn

            graphSettings = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Antialiasing cleans up the jagged lines and defines rendering
            // rules

            graphSettings.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            // Defines the line width of the stroke

            graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

            // Iterators created to cycle through strokes and fills
            Iterator<Color> strokeCounter = shapeStroke.iterator();
            Iterator<Color> fillCounter = shapeFill.iterator();

            // Iterator for transparency

            Iterator<Float> transCounter = transPercent.iterator();

            for (Shape s : shapes) {

                // Sets the shapes transparency value

                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                        AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, transCounter.next()));

                // Grabs the next stroke from the color arraylist
                graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());

                graphSettings.draw(s);

                // Grabs the next fill from the color arraylist
                graphSettings.setPaint(fillCounter.next());

                graphSettings.fill(s);
            }

            // Guide shape used for drawing
            if (drawStart != null && drawEnd != null) {
                // Makes the guide shape transparent

                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                        AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));

                // Make guide shape gray for professional look

                graphSettings.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                Shape aShape = null;

                if (currentAction == 2) {
                    aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                } else

                if (currentAction == 3) {
                    aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                } else

                if (currentAction == 4) {

                    // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates

                    aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                }

                graphSettings.draw(aShape);
            }
        }

        private Rectangle2D.Float drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            // Get the top left hand corner for the shape
            // Math.min returns the points closest to 0

            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);

            // Gets the difference between the coordinates and

            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }

        // The other shapes will work similarly
        // More on this in the next tutorial

        private Ellipse2D.Float drawEllipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }

        private Line2D.Float drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

            return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

        private Ellipse2D.Float drawBrush(int x1, int y1, int brushStrokeWidth,
                int brushStrokeHeight) {

            return new Ellipse2D.Float(x1, y1, brushStrokeWidth,
                    brushStrokeHeight);

        }

    }

    // Implements ActionListener so it can react to events on components

    private class ListenForSlider implements ChangeListener {

        // Called when the spinner is changed

        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

            // Check if the source of the event was the button

            if (e.getSource() == transSlider) {

                // Change the value for the label next to the spinner
                // Use decimal format to make sure only 2 decimals are ever
                // displayed

                transLabel.setText("Transparent: "
                        + dec.format(transSlider.getValue() * .01));

                // Set the value for transparency for every shape drawn after

                transparentVal = (float) (transSlider.getValue() * .01);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Woooooooooooooow superrrrrrbeee!! thank you a lot. IT WORKS perfectly :D

Comment: Can you please help me to enable the components to move when using the mouse?

Comment: @WJCM: You're going to have to extract the data from your application into model classes to manipulate them.  Generally, when making a complex GUI, you use the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to separate the parts of the GUI and allow you to focus on one part at a time.

Comment: Thank you Sir. You are so helpful. Can i revert back to you if i have any other issues?

Comment: @WJCM: Search Google first, and if that doesn't help, post your question.  It helps if you create a minimal, runnable example of your question.

Comment: Ok. Great. I'll focus on that part. It's for my final year dissertation. Thank you.